# Less verbose Stopwatch

Tags: c#, .net, logging, performance-testing, stopwatch

I recently came across a pair of functions from js-land that I rather like:

```
console.time("CalcPrimes");
// Go calculate primes
console.timeEnd("CalcPrimes");
// Outputs something like > CalcPrimes: 2150ms
```

Behind the scenes it's a [simple dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15348452/945456) that records the starting timestamp and prints duration by subtracting start time from end time.

Compare this with .NET code:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// Go calculate primes
sw.Stop();
Trace.WriteLine("CalcPrimes:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

My naive code requires twice as many lines to do the same thing (Note: you can do it in just two). However, I still have to manually format output. When I have to inject non-core logic into my app, I want the least clutter possible. Mostly, I'm against the duplicate logic to format the output everywhere I might time something.

---

1. Are there *existing solutions* in the .NET world for a less verbose timer/stopwatch?
2. If not, what *dangers should I be aware of* in creating a similar solution to the js code? (or example, should I use a `Dictionary<String, Stopwatch>` instead of saving off `Date.Now` due to precision issues?

Comment: You could refactor the object instantiation and `Start` invocation into a new method on a static helper class, and the `Stop` and `Trace` calls as well. But, really, is this so offensive? IMHO this is hardly *verbose*.

Comment: FWIW, you could use `var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()` and save a line.

Comment: I agree with @Yuck. It wouldn't be hard to implement this yourself, but given the complexities of multithreading (which JS doesn't have), the C# way of doing things looks a lot better.

Comment: @Yuck From the answers/comments it looks like I can reduce the lines of code quite a bit. I think what I'm mostly opposed to is the duplication of output formatting logic. I'm seen a lot of inconsistency (and sometimes downright incorrect code) in apps I've worked on, so I'd really like to *just do in right, once*. A static helper method sounds like the right path to take here.

Answer (score 4):

How about writing an helper method like

```
long ElapsedMilliseconds(int n, Action action)
{
    action(); 
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        action();
    }
    return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

and call it

```
var duration = ElapsedMilliseconds(5, ()=>CalculatePrimes());
```

Comment: I like this, definitely some appeal to have a diagnostic method that accepts an arbitrary method. I'll add only that if you'd planning to do anything more complex than this it may be better to seek out a dedicated library.

Comment: +1 for sure, I think I prefer `return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/((double)n);` but that is just a variation.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Go calculate primes
Trace.WriteLine("CalcPrimes: {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

I have found this extension useful:

```
public static class StopwatchExt
{
    public static string GetTimeString(this Stopwatch stopwatch, int numberofDigits = 1)
    {
        double s = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency;
        if (s > 1)
            return Math.Round(s, numberofDigits) + " s";
        if (s > 1e-3)
            return Math.Round(1e3 * s, numberofDigits) + " ms";
        if (s > 1e-6)
            return Math.Round(1e6 * s, numberofDigits) + " µs";
        if (s > 1e-9)
            return Math.Round(1e9 * s, numberofDigits) + " ns";
        return stopwatch.ElapsedTicks + " ticks";
    }
}
```